# Why doesn't my formula calculate a value in WHILE loop?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to get the mid-calculating result for my piece of console code.
The task is the following:
There is a total of **A** tonnes of vegs in a warehouse.
In the end of a month 1 we take **B** tonnes to be sold, in the end of 2nd month - **(1.1*B)**, in the end of M month we take **(1+(M-1)/10)*B** tonnes. We have the limit of 10 months (we shall not calculate for more than 10 months).
The initial A and B values are typed in by the user.

My code:

```
float A,B; 
int M = 1; 
... /here user types stuff in/...

while (M<10)
    {
        B = (1 + (M - 1) / 10) * B; // goddamn formula that can't execute normally
        cout << "It's " << M << " month, we took " << B << " tonnes of vegs." << endl;
        M++;
    }
```

What I type in:
A = 500; B = 1

What I expect should happen:
It's 1 month, we took 1 tonnes of vegs. 
*silent calculations: B= (1+(1-1)/10)*1 = 1; M= 1+1 = 2* 
 
It's 2 month, we took 1.1 tonnes of vegs. 
*silent calculations: B= (1+(2-1)/10)*1 = 1.1; M= 2+1 = 3* 
 
It's 3 month, we took 1.32 tonnes of vegs. 
*silent calculations: B= (1+(3-1)/10)*1.1 = 1.32; M= 3+1 = 4*
and so on until we reach the 10th month.

What I see instead:
It's 1 month, we took 1 tonnes of vegs
It's 2 month, we took 1 tonnes of vegs
It's 3 month, we took 1 tonnes of vegs
And so on, so the months are calculating but the formula from the task doesn't.
 Whichever value of B I place instead is always being shown.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here.It's specially important to post a [mcve].

Comment: Post a [MCVE] and your observations when inspecting the code with a debugger please.

Comment: "here user types stuff in" _Show us_

Comment: Your expectations are not right. You keep writing `*1` for subsequent months but it's `*B` and `B` keeps changing (ideally)

Comment: oh my yep. you have a sharp eye :) ofc it should change. thank you for the help )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`M` is an `int`. So, `(1 + (M - 1) / 10)` is an `int` too. That division is integer division. You're never going to get 1.1 out of it. It'll be truncated to 1. Every time.

Use `/ 10.0` there to force it all to be floating-point.

Comment: @DevSolar That would not be appropriate for a "month number", and would probably make the user input part too relaxed.

Comment: I should have gone to bed an hour ago.

Comment: 10.0 will be statically typed to double. Maybe you'd better recommend the use of '10f' or '(float)10'

Comment: @zertyz Doesn't really matter. I would typically use double rather than float all around, actually, but even here where `B` is float for whatever reason I'd rather not bloat the calculation with extra gumpf on my literals that doesn't serve any practical benefit. But I can see why you'd want to keep it symmetrical so wouldn't reject that change at code review.